# AVAudioPlayer audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully: not called

Tags: objective-c, audio, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am facing a weird issue with the AVAudioPlayer class with the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` callback not being called *sometimes*. A stripped down version of the code that starts the playback looks like,

```
self.player = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:localFileAudioURL error:&error] autorelease];
self.player.delegate = self;
[player prepareToPlay];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.016f target:self selector:@selector(updatePlaybackProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[player play];
```

There is a timer that runs every 16 ms to show the playback progress. Whenever the audio playback finishes, and the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` callback is called, the timer will be invalidated. The callback code is,

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    [self.progressTimer invalidate];
    self.progressTimer = nil;
}
```

However, occasionally (once in 20-30 playbacks) this callback is not called. I've added breakpoints and logging calls to verify that this callback method was not called.

The numberOfLoops for playback is set to `0` so it does not repeat.

Here's some additional information if it helps. The repeating timer that is being created updates the UI with the current playback progress. Its code looks like,

```
- (void)updatePlaybackProgress {
    SoundCell *soundCell = [self soundCellForCurrentlyPlayingSound];

    NSTimeInterval progress = player.currentTime / player.duration;
    if (progress >= 0) {
        soundCell.progress = progress;
    }
}
```

The completion callback is not called *sometimes*, so the timer is not invalidated and is called after every 16 ms. I logged the values of `player.currentTime`, and `progress` inside the `updatePlaybackProgress` method, and it seems the playback is looping over and over. The value of `currentTime` keeps increasing from `0.0` to `1.0`, then back to `0.0` and starts over. The audio, however, is only played the very first time, and not continuously as the value of `currentTime` suggests.

This problem has happened for sounds with a duration of 1 second to over 30 seconds.

I am out of ideas at this point, and Google and the Apple Developer Forums don't have anything related.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: I followed the advice from @drunknbass and used a `CADisplayLink` instead of a 16ms timer to update the display. I also set the frequency high enough hoping that would fix the problem. The display frequency is 60hz (around 16ms), and I set it to update every 5th refresh cycle (approximately every 80ms). The problem wasn't happening as frequently, but I was still able to reproduce it unfortunately.

Comment: But my problem is different. I want to do some operations after audio player finishes playing. My entire logic depends on didfinishplaying call back function. But some times it is not getting fired. I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: @gladiator2345 - Are you using any timers to update the UI or something else while the audio is playing?

Comment: No. In my case i have to play a short sound, sometimes multiple files and when it finishes i have to do something else.I gave view controller as delegate of my audio handling class which in turn registers as delegate of the avplayer. I get callback most of the times when audio finishes playing. But some times it misses. I am making this app for ipad3. It is a musical instrument based app.

Answer (score 1):

1. your timer is not guaranteed to fire at the time you specify. If you are trying to build a player progress indicator i suggest using a CADisplayLink to give you nstimer like functionality without the overhead(its fired based off screen refresh).
2. i would implement ALL of the AVAudioPlayerDelegate Protocol methods associated with playback..

Responding to Sound Playback Completion
– audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:
Responding to an Audio Decoding Error
– audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:error:
Handling Audio Interruptions
– audioPlayerBeginInterruption:
– audioPlayerEndInterruption:
– audioPlayerEndInterruption:withFlags:

Most likely one of them is called when playback stops. You can also register for NSNotifications for audio playback, and in the method you implement you'd just need to compare the audioplayer with your local player to know this was something youd be interested in.

Comment: Thanks for `CADisplayLink`. I was not aware of it. I have implemented all 4 delegate methods of `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`, and neither of them were called based on logging calls. I haven't tried checking for notifications yet. Could the timer's high frequency somehow be blocking the callback from happening? NSNotifications are queued up as far as I know and not discarded. Trying it out now.

Comment: I tried for about 15 minutes to reproduce the problem, but it hasn't happened yet. The behavior is very inconsistent. Is 16 ms or 62.5 hz to high a frequency for NSTimer updates?

Comment: I'm using `CADisplayLink`, and the issue occurs far less often than it used to. Actually, I have only seen it twice since the last month. But the fact that it still happened at all is bothering